# CSASPNETMessageBox in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement a message box in ASP.NET C#. I added all the code from this web link:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETMessageBox-3e8c6273

Then I used the Message Box to check for empty values in Btn_AddUser_Click as follows:

```
        protected void Btn_AddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Txt_UserID.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox();
                messageBox.MessageTitle = "MYAPP1";
                messageBox.MessageIcons = MessageBox.MessageBoxIcons.Error;
                messageBox.MessageText = "Please Enter User ID";
                Literal1.Text = messageBox.Show(this);
                return;
            }
            if (Txt_Password.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox();
                messageBox.MessageTitle = "MYAPP1";
                messageBox.MessageIcons = MessageBox.MessageBoxIcons.Error;
                messageBox.MessageText = "Please Enter Password";
                Literal1.Text = messageBox.Show(this);
                return;
            }
            if (Txt_Department.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox();
                messageBox.MessageTitle = "MYAPP1";
                messageBox.MessageIcons = MessageBox.MessageBoxIcons.Error;
                messageBox.MessageText = "Please Enter Department";
                Literal1.Text = messageBox.Show(this);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox();
            messageBox.MessageTitle = "MYAPP1";
            messageBox.MessageIcons = MessageBox.MessageBoxIcons.Error;
            messageBox.MessageText = ex.Message;
            Literal1.Text = messageBox.Show(this);
        }
    }
```

When I tested this code, the following happens:

1. All three text boxes empty and clicked `Btn_AddUser`:
   Received Message: "Please Enter User ID"
2. Filled User ID and clicked `Btn_AddUser`:
   Received Message: "Please Enter Password"
3. Filled Password and clicked `Btn_AddUser`:
   Received Message: "Please Enter Department"
4. Filled Password (as it was not posted back) and Department and clicked `Btn_AddUser`:

This time, the code does not exit successfully. Instead the Message Box 'Please Enter Department' appears again and clicking OK does not make the Message Box disappear. The application halts with the message box 'Please Enter Department' appearing on the screen.

My question is how disappear the message box when all the three text boxes are filled.

Message box is shown even if all the text boxes are filled. When all three text boxes are filled and `Btn_AddUser` is clicked, Message box still shows the message 'Please Enter Department' and the application halts.

Comment: My question is how not to show the message box when all the three text boxes are filled. Message box is shown even if all the text boxes are filled. When all three text boxes are filled and Btn_AddUser is clicked, Message box still shows the message 'Please Enter Department' and the application halts.

Comment: Then add this in your question.

Comment: Debug and check what you get in `Txt_Department.Text`

Comment: Thanks. I added the above text in the question.

Comment: Debugging results: When Txt_Department.Text is empty and clicked the button, program entered in this if: if (Txt_Department.Text == string.Empty). When Txt_Department.Text is filled, program did not enter in any if statement and reached the last bracket of Btn_AddUser_Click. From here the flow went to this line in MessageBoxUserControl.ascx: <link href="../Styles/MessageBox.css?t=<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> After executing this line, the Message box appeared with the message Please Enter Department and the application halted.